How to add items to listbox if not exist?
I'm having an issue with my code, I'm trying to add items from a Directory to a ListBox, the issue is that I keep getting the same items (duplicated) over and over again.
here is my code:
String[] filesDir = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\FOLDER");
foreach (string file in filesDir)
  if (!this.listbox1.Items.Contains(file))
  {
    listbox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file ) + @"  found");
  }


What you add and what you check are different things.

The string you are checking to see if it exists in the ListBox is different from the string being added.
The modification of the code is as follows:
String[] filesDir = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\FOLDER");
foreach (string file in filesDir)
{
    var NewLineText = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + @"  found";
    if (!this.listBox1.Items.Contains(NewLineText))
        listBox1.Items.Add(NewLineText);
} 


oups, didn't noticed that, must tuesday, thanks Deniz

@Anthony Magerera, I'm glad your problem is solved.
